# Is it possible to fine-tune a tensorflow model using pre-trained model from pyTorch?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, onnx

What I tried so far:

1. pre-train a model using unsupervised method in PyTorch, and save off the checkpoint file (using `torch.save(state, filename)`)
2. convert the checkpoint file to onnx format (using `torch.onnx.export`)
3. convert the onnx to tensorflow saved model (using `onnx-tf`)
4. trying to load the variables in saved_model folder as checkpoint in my tensorflow training code (using `tf.train.init_from_checkpoint`) for fine-tuning

But now I am getting stuck at step 4 because I notice that `variables.index` and `variables.data@1` files are basically empty (probably because of this: https://github.com/onnx/onnx-tensorflow/issues/994)

Also, specifically, if I try to use `tf.train.NewCheckpointReader` to load the files and call `ckpt_reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()`, `_CHECKPOINTABLE_OBJECT_GRAPH`  is empty

Any suggestions/experience are appreciated :-)